# Low upvote contrast under the "Linked" and "Related" headings

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

This is my first meta post, so if I have done anything wrong, please alert me.

While browsing a question, I noticed that the upvote counts for the links under the "**[Related](https://gyazo.com/43f3befb9cd5bbb372863d1440e223ff)**" and "[**Linked**](https://gyazo.com/348e111c4d48f7b107514cdb56b8cf2d)" heading have extremely low contrast, to the point that, (for me), they are barely visible.

I found this under Google Chrome v55.0.2883.87 m, the latest Windows 10, Nvidia GeForce 940m (driver v376.33 ), and Intel HD Graphics 4600. Also, I *do* have full colour vision and my vision is not impaired in any way.

Is it intended? Or is it just me? I just wanted to bring it to the attention of whoever does the styling.